# What should a new player focus on?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

Escape from Tarkov is a complex game, with many ways to "progress". As a new player, I feel like I am "running in circles", and not really moving forward. As such, I would like to know what is recommended for a new player to focus on. Examples include:

- Player level (Lv. 10 unlocks the Flea Market, for example)
- Trader level (New weapons, ammo, armor, etc.)
- Money (Self explanatory)
- Hideout
- Cases for storage space

Right now, I feel myself trying to do "a bit of everything", and I feel like I end up not making progress in any of these things. What should I focus on?

Comment: Go to the various existing resources that will provide much more information. https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_Play_Guide_for_Escape_from_Tarkov https://www.reddit.com/r/EscapefromTarkov/ - and youtube guides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really tough question, after the first two choices.

It is imperative that you get to level 10 as fast as possible to unlock the flea market. Having access to literally every item in the game is a key factor in future progression, and it’ll allow you to sell your gear for a greater price than you’d be able to get from a dealer.

The second need is to manage your stash space through either upgrading your stash or acquiring cases. For non Edge-of-Darkness who don’t already begin with massive stashes you’ll be wanting for more space to store your knick knacks. Through either purchases from a dealer (Ammo boxes and Med Cases are both easy exchanges) or purchasing from the flea market you need get a case to manage your limited inventory. I’d recommend getting the lucky scav junk box, but really you can get what both meets your needs and fits your budget.

After those immediate needs are met you’re free to play as you desire. A helpful secondary goal would be to use quests to reach the level 20 milestone, which leads to expanded dealer capabilities and hideout upgrades but you can do what you want

Comment: I would agree for the most part. Bumrush level 10, and then I would say quest as much as you can to increase dealer loyalty. Stash management kind of is an all the time effort and you'll need to upgrade your stash in your hideout as well. Most of your cases will probably come from the flea, as dealers don't unlock many until further into their loyalty. Questing also will reward you with some as well, but not for a while, and the quests get much more challenging.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive guide. I'm stuck on level 9 and don't seem to have much luck finding scavs to kill as PMC. And of course, any encounter with a PMC will end up with my demise. My Lv. 2 body armor and Lv. 3 helmet stand no chance against any meta gun with end-game bullets :D

Comment: There's numerous guides and videos out there that give solid information. I'd recommend going and watching Pestily, or any of the other big Tarkov names for beginner guides. I'd also add look up the maps while you play and learn them - you can learn where scavs spawn to hunt them if that's your goal for a quest/practice.